# Upgrading Bowden Tube on Ender 6 to Capricorn

Tags: bowden, creality-ender-6

I'm very new into 3D printing.

I brought an Ender 6 and a cover for ABS printing, but the standard white Bowden tube was too short to pass through the hole of the cover. So I'm replacing the Bowden tube for a Capricorn one.

However, the manufacturer (Captubes.com) only states that their 2 meter [kit](https://www.captubes.com/shop/#!/XS-Creality-Kit-2-Meter/p/123266814/category=23214267) is compatible with CR-10 and Ender 3.

Is this kit also compatible with an Ender 6?

Comment: You only need a tube, why order a complete kit? Furthermore, it is very unwise to have really long Bowden tubes (2 meters), this will affect printing quality and at least tuning the printer for the new length. Think of problems with e.g. stringing.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I was really thinking the entire kit would be necessary. I'd actually cut the tube to around 1.1m or 1.2m so that it passes the hole on the cover. Did some measuring here with a string. I have no idea why anyone would manufacture a cover for the Ender 6 that fits perfectly over it, but not design the hole at the proper height.

Comment: Consider printing other filaments than ABS (that shrink less), nowadays there are better filament types such that ABS isn't really necessary anymore. ABS is mostly replaced by co-polymer filament.

Comment: I'll look more closely into those co-polymer filaments, @0scar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up getting in contact with the sales team at Captubes.com, and they replied promptly, what I did not expect.
They claim that the Capricorn tube is indeed compatible with the Ender 6 printer, and that they use the same fittings, with the exception of pro printers and ones that use something called a Bondtech extruder.
I'd like to thank everyone that helped to clear this matter.

Comment: If this solved your problem, feel free to accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to move the E motor outside the enclosure. Don't do that. Bowden extruders *already* suffer from severely reduced accuracy and increased difficulty in pushing the filament through the tube length. Making the tube longer makes this a lot worse. Instead, feed the extruder, which remains in its existing place inside the enclosure, with an "reverse bowden tube" bringing filament in from outside the enclosure. Or optionally, at ABS chamber temperatures that should be well under the temperature at which ABS softens, just put the filament spool inside the heated enclosure.

Comment: I do exactly the same, I use a tube in front of the extruder to pull the filament from the spool from a container. +1